# Azure Build pipeline : checkout task done from scratch at each source update

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline on Azure Devops which works fine. On first launch, the project is checked out, which is quite long, then the task is launched.
On the next run, the 'checkout' step is pretty quick and the task is launched.

The problem I have is that when I make a change in my sources - even the smallest - that is detected by the build, the checkout step is done again from scratch which is very long. I tried to find if there is an option in order to keep unchanged data but I couldn't find it.
As I don't clean sources in the initial tasks, I expected this step duration to be proportional to the source files changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually on another build I don't have the problem.

Updates are taken into account and the checkout phase lasts less than 10 seconds. I'll use that one as template.

Curiousely the 'clean' flag is set to true ?

Anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

i think the default is to perform a clean checkout, there are a couple of settings for the checkout process [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout). I think your best bet is `clean: false` and `fetchDepth: 1` (shallow checkout). I'm not sure the first one does what you ask for. second one will definitely speed up the checkout

Comment: well, the problem is that I've already done that and the problem remains. There is an option to 'tag' sources in case of success/never/always, do you know what it is used for ?

Comment: the tag sources is not related to your issue. the `fetchDepth: 1` doesn't help?

Comment: no, it doesn't seem to have any effect. The process checks out my sources, do you know if there is a way to disable this ?

Comment: i dont think there is a way of doing so. well, you can do: `- checkout: none` but that will always skip the checkout